# jquery show dropdown from dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I'm using a nice script that lets me choose from a 'colors'-dropdown. When I select the first option, I placed another 'numbers'-dropdown in it. But now the problem: when I select something in this 'numbers'-dropdown everything the selectmenu dissapears. I want it to stay and give its own hyperlinks. My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Select Box</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"> </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("select").change(function(){
    $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
        if($(this).attr("value")=="red"){
            $(".box").not(".red").hide();
            $(".red").show();
        }
        else if($(this).attr("value")=="green"){
            $(".box").not(".green").hide();
            $(".green").show();
        }
        else if($(this).attr("value")=="blue"){
            $(".box").not(".blue").hide();
            $(".blue").show();
        }
        else{
            $(".box").hide();
        }
    });
}).change();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <select>
        <option>Choose Color</option>
        <option value="red">Red</option>
        <option value="green">Green</option>
        <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="red box" style="margin-top:10px;"><select>
        <option>Choose number</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select></div>
<div class="green box">You have selected <strong>green option</strong> so i am here</div>
<div class="blue box">You have selected <strong>blue option</strong> so i am here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are firing this `$("select").change(function(){` event when either `select` is changed. Make the following changes:

```
<select id="colorSelect">
    <option>Choose Color</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
</select>

$("#colorSelect").change(function(){
```

This way it will only fire when the color `select` is changed not the number `select`...

If you fire it on the number `select` this part of the `if` statement will be executed:

```
else {
    $(".box").hide();
}
```

which will hide all boxes.

Working Example:

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#colorSelect").change(function(){
    $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
        if($(this).attr("value")=="red"){
            $(".box").not(".red").hide();
            $(".red").show();
        }
        else if($(this).attr("value")=="green"){
            $(".box").not(".green").hide();
            $(".green").show();
        }
        else if($(this).attr("value")=="blue"){
            $(".box").not(".blue").hide();
            $(".blue").show();
        }
        else{
            $(".box").hide();
        }
    });
}).change();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Select Box</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"> </script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <select id="colorSelect">
        <option>Choose Color</option>
        <option value="red">Red</option>
        <option value="green">Green</option>
        <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="red box" style="margin-top:10px;"><select>
        <option>Choose number</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select></div>
<div class="green box">You have selected <strong>green option</strong> so i am here</div>
<div class="blue box">You have selected <strong>blue option</strong> so i am here</div>
</body>
</html>
```